# No provider for CallNumber in ionic 3

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3, I want to call a number and for that I have added ionic native plugin for call-number:

```
ionic cordova plugin add call-number
npm install --save @ionic-native/call-number
```

But it's throwing an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for CallNumber!

Comment: Sounds like you need to add it to your `providers` in app.module.ts

Answer (score 12):

You also need to add `CallNumber` in the `providers` array of your `AppModule` (located in the `app.module.ts` file):

```
// ...
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [..],
  imports: [...],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [
    CallNumber, // <--- Here! :)
    ...
    ...
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Shame that it is not well documentated on the Ionic documentation

Answer (score 3):

Add as a provider inside app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    CallNumber, 
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

### add below code in your page.ts file

```
@Component({
selector: '',
templateUrl : '',
providers : [CallNumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution by simply using

```
<a href="tel:+1234567890">CALL</a>
```

Just make sure you have below code in config.xml file

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```