# How to convert XML link to Json Link and how to use it on ionic 3?

Tags: json, xml, angular, ionic3, converters

As you can see in the title, i would like to convert an `XML` link to Json link.
I'm new on `ionic` so i'm trying to lean new things.

i tried to do like this tutorial: https://www.ionicrun.com/transform-xml-to-json-in-ionic-2-with-angular-4-3/

but i got this issue:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> DataProvider]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> DataProvider]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for DataProvider! Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> DataProvider]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> DataProvider]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for DataProvider!

I have no idea how to solve it.

home.ts

...

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient, public dataProvide: DataProvider, public transformProvider: TransformProvider) {
    this.x2j();
  }

x2j(){
  this
  .dataProvide
  .getRandomUser()
  .pipe(
    map((res: string) => this.transformProvider.convertToJson(res))
  )
  .subscribe((res: Object) => {
    console.dir(res);
  });
}
```

if you have another way to convert `xml->Json` tell me

Thanks all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for CallNumber in ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484486/no-provider-for-callnumber-in-ionic-3)

Comment: I added on providers DataProvider, and it works !